# Flask-SQLAlchemy session.rollback doesnt work

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I´m developing an API with FLASK and I´m using FLASK-SQALCHEMY.

Well, when the api throws some exception, I try to rollback the session.

**My Code**

```
def create_user():
    user = User()
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.flush()
    return user

try:
    new_user = create_user()
    print('x' + 2) # force error
    db.session.commit()
except Exception as error:
    db.session.rollback()
    raise
```

**My requirements (Python 3.6.3 & MySQL 5.7):**

```
SQLAlchemy==1.2.2
astroid==1.6.0
flask==0.12.2
flask-login==0.4.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
flask-script==2.0.6
flask-sqlalchemy==2.3.2
flask-validator==1.2.3
isort==4.2.15
pygelf==0.3.3
pylint==1.8.1
PyMySQL==0.7.11
pytest==3.3.1
Werkzeug==0.13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flush.html):

> The FLUSH statement causes an implicit commit

Remove the `db.session.flush()` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Do you know if PostgreSQL does the same?

Comment: I would think so, but truthfully I'm not that familiar with the nuance of Postgres transactions.

Comment: I tried now with the PostgreSQL, and it really doesnt do the same. o/ .... So, I will use PostgreSQL. Thanks again, man

Comment: What, SQLAlchemy's [`Session.flush()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) is not/does not emit MySQL FLUSH statement. It flushes the changes held by the `Session` to the DB, aka issues inserts, updates and deletes. What might actually apply is the note on autocommit.

Comment: Is there any chance can rollback a commit